# Unbound not returning A records over IPv6

Tags: domain-name-system, pfsense, unbound, opnsense

I recently replaced my pfSense installation with [OPNsense](https://opnsense.org/) and have been struggling a bit with the Unbound installation.

In short, it's IPv6 enabled and everything works well (both IPv6 and IPv4) in general. However, it seems to struggle with DNS look-ups for A Records over IPv6.

Here's an example:

```
> $ dig +short -6 switch0.my.tld @[redacted]::1
> $ dig +short -6 ipv6.google.com @[redacted[::1
ipv6.l.google.com.
```

As you can see, the DNS lookup for ipv6.google.com works fine, but not for my domain.

Now, if I do the same query towards the same server but over IPv4, it works fine:

```
> $ dig +short switch0.my.tld @192.168.200.1
192.168.200.2
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything basic here, but I don't understand why Unbound is not returning the A record over IPv6, but it works over IPv6.

Other IPv4 queries works just fine:

```
> dig +short -6 google.com @[redacted]::1
172.217.21.142
```

Comment: I don't know unbound but if I were to guess - I would say you have some kind of access rules on your zone which deny access from IPv6.

Comment: Interesting lead. Will take a look.

Comment: Added my local IPv6 /64 but still no dice. Good shout tho.

Comment: Can you try to capture network traffic and have a look at it in wireshark? Or at least try `dig` with some verbose / debugging options to check what kind of error response you are getting.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you remove +short for any kind of troubleshooting